# How do I read query results dynamically?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using mysql and node. I need to print only a 'part' of the query result and this 'part' is set to be different each time.

```
// var val = any one of a,b,c or d.
// This is updated by some other part of code.

con.query("SELECT a,b,c,d FROM new_table LIMIT 1", 
    function(error, results, fields) {


if (error)                                                                                                                                                  
  throw error;
```

I want to print only the data from column represented by 'val' and not the data from other columns. 
Since the value of 'val' changes dynamically, how do I proceed upon this ?

```
console.log(results.val);
```

This doesn't seem to work, neither is this,

```
console.log(results.'val');
```

Comment: If you only want 1 column, you should select only this column in your query. How/when does `val` change and where do you want this change to be visible?

Comment: try `results[val]`

Comment: @DanFromGermany : val changes as per the data from user ( after a lot of processing ). If I select only val, still I'd have to read it's response from the row packet data and how do I do that without knowing what that column is ?                ADyson, I've tried this and this is not working.

Comment: Who, if not you, knows about this a, b, c, d logic? I don't know what your a, b, c or d is :-) I suspect your database scheme to be inaccurate.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I used a,b,c and d as an example. My use case is very complex and that would need for me to write two pages of explanation: / My db schemes seem right to me. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: It occurs to me that results is probably an array actually. So you perhaps need to loop through `results` and print the value from each row. e.g. `for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { console.log(results[i][val]); }` - try that and let me know.

Comment: If that's still not a solution then please give us an example of the content of `val` and also an example of the content of `results`. Then we can be clearer about what's happening.

Comment: P.S. I saw your comment by chance because I decided to check the question. If you want to notify someone of your comment and be certain they will see it, type @ and then start to type their username e.g. @sur - and then select the final value from the little pop-up box just above the comment

Comment: Thanks man @ADyson. I couldn't tag you, since stack overflow allows only one tag per comment and had already tagged DanFromGermany. This ain't working man. However, I fixed this issue by using flags and kinda hard-coding. Thanks for your help, anyways.